# Centrar grupo de divs en CSS

Tags: html, css

me gustaría saber cómo sería posible alinear un grupo de divs (4 divs) de la siguiente manera:

[image: Imagen]

He probado a hacerlo con float:left, pero si lo hago, se me salen fuera del div principal. Además, como se ve en la imagen, quiero que haya margen entre ellos. La cosa es que no encuentro la manera de disponerlos de esa manera, no se me ocurre otra cosa más que posicionarlos individualmente, pero estoy convencido de que se puede hacer más fácilmente.

Comment: Mejor si pones el código HTML y el CSS que tengas aunque no funcione para que sea más facil ayudarte. Hay varias maneras de conseguir esa disposición de los elementos: con floats, flexbox y quiza alguna más pero primero deberías enseñar tu código.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si en un elemento HTML todos sus hijos usan la propiedad CSS `float` el elemento se colapsará y se mostrará con tamaño 0. Esta es una de las rarezas del CSS que debes tener en cuenta al usar el layout con floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el ancho y alto de las cuatro cajas es conocido y fijo, utilizando flexbox y calc (IE10+) se puede lograr de esta manera.

Quiero hacer una aclaración: flexbox es ideal para layouts de una sola dimensión, por lo cual en este caso puede no ser la mejor solución. En el futuro cerceno tendremos grillas nativas con css que resolverán este problema de una forma mucho más sencilla.

```css
.contenedor {
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;  
}

.cajas {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.caja {
  background-color: red;
  margin: calc(25% - 50px);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1>Título centrado</h1>
  <h2>Subtítulo centrado</h2>

  <div class="cajas">
    <div class="caja">
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo añadiría 2 divs mas. Uno para cada columna y otro para los subobjetos de la parte de abajo del titulo que solo abarque las dos columnas.

Comment: ¿Cómo quedaría el código entonces? Sobre todo el CSS

Comment: Es mejor si añades código de lo que propones para ver cómo sería tu solución.

Answer (score 0):

Una aproximación rápida puede ser la siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Título centrado</h1>
  <h2>Subtítulo centrado</h2>

  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
}


.box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10em;
  bottom: 10em;
  left: 10em;
  right: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

También lo podrías conseguir usando las cajas flexibles o [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS).

[Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/eledgaar/7fyLrrq8/) el ejemplo funcionando.